# Jenkins to trigger another build/project dynamically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-workflow

Is there a way in Jenkins to trigger another build/project dynamically based on a parameter value in parent project?

The reason for this is that I have 100's of projects and I don't want to use pipeline/conditional post build plugins to link all jobs.

I know of a way using REST API but trying to find is there a way to trigger a single project from those 100?

Comment: You can trigger a build for a project if another has succeded or failed. Check the "Build Triggers" section in project configuration.

Comment: Thx but i would prefer based on a parameter  and project dynamically

Comment: When you say "pipeline/conditional post build plugins to link all jobs", do you mean you wouldn't use something like https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin ?

Comment: Sorry I'm sort of new to Jenkins. Can i add conditional logic before triggering

Comment: You can use Conditional Build Step plugin with Parameterized Trigger plugin inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with [Pipeline Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin). Just define your parameter (say `MY_DOWNSTREAM_JOB`) and use it inside the groovy script definition:

```
build MY_DOWNSTREAM_JOB
```

Comment: Thanks,  could you please provide the URL for groovy plugin? Which plugin to use?  Saw couple of them

Comment: You mean Pipeline Plugin I guess. It's my answer.